# Ubuntu 12.04 - No internet connection

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection

I've recently installed ubuntu 12.04 on an old dell pc, which I'm using as media center. I have an ethernet cable plugged in from the pc directly to the router.

There's nothing wrong with the network card as its I can access the pc from my laptop using Chicken VNC.

My ifconfig looks like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:1f:59:b1:5e  
          inet addr:192.168.1.21  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:1fff:fe59:b15e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15360 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19712 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1640979 (1.6 MB)  TX bytes:17863489 (17.8 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8534 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8534 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:664924 (664.9 KB)  TX bytes:664924 (664.9 KB)
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: The output of `ifconfig` looks OK. There is an IP address, and seemingly no errors. I've no idea what you mean by "no internet connection", but the next step would be to try pinging google, like this: `ping -c4 google.com` or like this `ping -c4 173.194.70.101`.

Comment: @mikewhatever When I say 'no internet connection' I mean I can't access the internet at all. I tried pinging google.com but I get 'unknown host google.com'.

Comment: Hm..., what about the other ping command? If it works, then you have a DNS problem we should investigate.

Comment: ok, ping -c4 173.194.70.101 worked. So what does that mean ?

Comment: That means there is a DNS problem (usually easily solved). Click on the network icon in the panel, and select Connection Information. What does it say next to Default Route: and Primary DNS:?

Comment: Default Route: 192.168.1.1 and Primary DNS: 89.101.160.4

Comment: OK, the two should be the same (as Default Gateway) when connected to a router. Edit your wired connection (by selecting Edit connections) and remove the 89.101.160.4 from the DNS field, or, if it's empty, add 192.168.1.1, save it, and then disconnect and re-connect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6606/discussion-between-stephen-and-mikewhatever)

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to login first. Here, I use the launchpad ID, and it isn't available there.

Comment: The screenshot looks good. If 192.168.1.1 doesn't work, try 8.8.8.8, which is Google DNS. ...still trying to login.

Comment: For the life of me, I couldn't login to that chat site, no matter what I tied, sorry about that. I hope the comments here have been helpful and the problem is resolved. If not, and you need more help, let me know.

Comment: @mikewhatever I tried the 8.8.8.8 but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Stephen Connect your PC to your router and check what is the Primary DNS.

Comment: please post your `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @Stephen - We need to see all the information within your question itself. Please edit your question with the questions and answers in the comments above.  Flag - and we'll clean up the comments.

Comment: @Stephen I'm just basing this on  mikewhatever's suggestions. He asked you to set DNS to default route. On my machine the default route is 192.168.52.1 and primary DNS is 192.168.52.2 (secondary 192.168.52.5) So why not try 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 ... for your DNS. Might work.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of such problems is misconfiguration of the resolvconf package. Try running the following in a terminal on the PC.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Then reboot the PC.

If you still can't ping www.google.com but can ping a valid IP address on the Internet then you probably need to adjust the DNS configuration. If you are using ifup and /etc/network/interfaces then you need to add "dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8" to the "iface eth0" stanza in /etc/network/interfaces, where you can use 8.8.8.8 or some other working nameserver's address. If you are, instead, using NetworkManager then you should use the Connection Editor to enable the acquisition of nameserver addresses via DHCP (Set IPv4 Settings | Method to "Automatic (DHCP)" and not to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only") or to set static nameserver addresses for the Wired Connection.