# Ubuntu 12.04 no Internet connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

I have a laptop that dual boots to either Ubuntu 12.04 or Windows 7, but the I can't seem to do anything requiring an Internet connection on the Ubuntu side. I've been through the troubleshooting guide of clearing cache, restarting, etc. to no avail. The wireless icon on the top menu shows that I am connected to my wifi network but firefox doesn't work and I can't use ssh or sftp protocols either. The error message i get with Firefox is "Server not found." Any ideas are appreciated!

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:03:9a:34:9d:1d  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:41 Base address:0x8000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:1409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:125628 (125.6 KB)  TX bytes:125628 (125.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:53:2e:94:c2:b7  
      inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::8a53:2eff:fe94:c2b7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1109 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:172548 (172.5 KB)  TX bytes:84207 (84.2 KB)
```

ping google.com:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

ls -ld /etc/resolv.conf:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Aug 17  2012 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) 
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search hsd1.fl.comcast.net
```

ping -c4 192.168.1.1:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2999ms
```

ping 192.168.1.1:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 10056ms
pipe 3
```

route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

dmesg | grep wlan0:

```
[   28.289967] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   28.290703] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   35.980297] wlan0: authenticate with 00:23:69:c6:c9:c8 (try 1)
[   35.984082] wlan0: authenticated
[   35.992776] wlan0: associate with 00:23:69:c6:c9:c8 (try 1)
[   35.998868] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:23:69:c6:c9:c8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   35.998872] wlan0: associated
[   36.003690] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   46.419609] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

ifconfig (again):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:03:9a:34:9d:1d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:41 Base address:0x8000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:13468 (13.4 KB)  TX bytes:13468 (13.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:53:2e:94:c2:b7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a53:2eff:fe94:c2b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20780 (20.7 KB)  TX bytes:55633 (55.6 KB)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Do you get a error message? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/392145/edit) and add the information. Can you reach your own router? What happens when try to reach http://192.168.1.1?

Comment: MadMike, I added the Firefox error. Could you explain what you mean by "reach my own router"?  Thanks!

Comment: Try to disable/ignore IPv6. From your post I can see that from the router side everything seems to be ok, because an IP has been assigned to your machine and the config settings seem to be ok too.  Edit the wireless connection and set the IPv6 to be ignored and IPv4 to Automatic (DHCP).

Comment: Post the output of the command "ping google.com"

Comment: Jay - added result above. User123492 - just did that, but no difference. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Did you set the wlan0 ip address as a static ip address? Because it has definitely not got the ip address from an ISP otherwise you could have pinged google.

Comment: Jay - I don't think I know how to do that, how would I check?

Comment: There is clearly a problem with hostname resolution (DNS) - can you please add the output of `ls -ld /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question? @Jay a 192.168.x.x IP address is a private (LAN) address so it is either static or coming from a local DHCP server - being static would only matter if it conflicts with another active assignment on the LAN.

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225129/ubuntu-12-04-no-internet-connection?rq=1
Also, could be a duplicate.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness thanks for the link, but it doesn't look like that guy and I have the same problem. When I try the ping -c4 command to the same ip address in that thread I get a "Destination Host Unreachable" error. How can i find another ip address to try?

Comment: That's because you aren't online, so pinging an online site (such as google), wouldn't work, thus another IP wouldn't work. Did you try `ping -c4 google.com`?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness just did that, same result: "unknown host google.com". Thanks

Comment: Same thing as I mentioned before, you're not connected. I am relatively noobish in the world on networking, so I would wait for steeldriver to return. My attempts at answering are bound to screw something up. Hope you solve your problem!

Comment: If you get 'Destination host unreachable' for an external numeric IP such as 173.194.70.101 then that's the first issue you need to fix. FWIW your resolv.conf looks OK (although some people have had issues with comcast.net search domains). Can you ping your own router's gateway IP (probably 192.168.1.1)? What is the output of `route -n`? Are there any interesting error messages from `dmesg | grep wlan0`?

Comment: @steeldriver just added those results above.  I'll let you decide what is "interesting" as I have no idea.

Comment: Hmm... that's really quite a puzzle - your wlan0 device appears to have associated to the access point OK, your routing table looks OK - yet you can't even ping the gateway device. I don't know where to go from here. I know it sounds like desperation but have you tried restarting the router?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your DNS to Google's: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Also change search to: www.google.com

This can be done by right-clicking network, edit connections, select the one relating to the WiFi, Addresses, select DHCP (Addresses Only)

Comment: Okay, just changed IPv4 Settings to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only, then entered "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" into the "DNS servers" box, and "www.google.com" into the "Search domains" box. As per others' instructions I have IPv6 Settings method set to "Ignore". I'm still not able to ping google or access Internet, though. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Try the time-tested method known as reboot now. =]

Comment: believe me, I've tried that many times!  Whatever this problem is, it sure is frustrating. Nothing seems to be working and yet the menu bar shows I am connected and it still works fine on the Windows side.

Comment: post results of ifconfig again please.

Comment: just added to original post

Comment: try turning wifi card and then router off then back on.